# Modal not popping up on link click

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I need to pop up a modal dialog on clicking a link. I have scanned related questions and followed similar instructions,however, none of the solutions seem to work.
Picture below is how my page looks like. Clicking on "Update" should open a modal window.

[image]

Here is my EJS file.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF8">
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <link href="javascripts/frontend.js">
  <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="/stylesheets/userlist.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Amatic SC' rel='stylesheet'>
  <link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=NTR' rel='stylesheet'>



  <title>Userlist</title>
  <!-- <script>$(document).ready({

 });
 </script> -->
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <h1><strong>FORM</strong></h1>

      <hr id="hr2" style="border: 6px solid palevioletred">


      <form action="/users/add_user" class="form-horizontal" id="user_form" method="post" name="user_form">
        <fieldset>
          <!-- Text input-->


          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="textinput">Name :</label>

            <div class="col-md-4">
              <input class="form-control input-md" id="nameinput" name="name" onfocus="if (this.value=='Name') this.value='';" placeholder="Enter Username" type="text" value="Name">
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- Text input-->


          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="textinput">Age :</label>

            <div class="col-md-4">
              <input class="form-control input-md" id="ageinput" name="age" placeholder="Enter Age" type="number">
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- Button -->
          <!-- Button (Double) -->


          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-8">
              <button class="btn btn-success" id="singlebutton" type="submit"><b>Add User</b></button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </fieldset>
      </form>


      <h1><strong>USERS</strong>
      </h1>

      <hr id="hr1" style="border: 6px solid #7ec4ec;">


      <ul class="triangle" id="list">
        <!-- Link trigger modal -->
        <!-- Modal -->


        <li style="list-style: none; display: inline">

          <%for(var i=0; i<userlist.length; i++) {%>
        </li>


        <!-- ______ MODAL ______ -->

        <div aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" class="modal fade" id="openModal" role="dialog" tabindex="-1">
          <div class="modal-dialog" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
                <button aria-label="Close" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" type="button"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>

                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Edit :</h4>
              </div>


              <div class="modal-body">
                HEY!!
                <!--  <form>
          Name:<input id="nameId" name="modal_username" type="text" value=""> Age:<input id="ageId" name="modal_age" type="number" value="">
         </form> -->
              </div>


              <div class="modal-footer">
                <button class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" type="button">Close</button> <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">Save changes</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>


        <li>
          <%= userlist[i].name %>:
            <%= userlist[i].age %> <a class="delete_user" data-id="<%= userlist[i]._id %>" href="#" id="delete" title="Delete this User">Delete</a> || <a href="#openModal" class="update_user" data-target="#openModal" data-toggle="modal" id="update" title="Update user info"
                data-id="<%= userlist[i]._id %>">Update</a>
        </li>
        <%} %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I am using bootstrap 3.2.0 and have included jquery before bootstrap.

Comment: Can you try and put the jquery source file after the `body` tag and before `html` tag ends? and i think you need the boostrap.min.js also

Comment: @KaoriYui It worked. Needed to include bootstrap.min.js also. Got it mixed up with the bootstrap.min.css. You should post that as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try to put the dependencies after the `</body>` tag and before the `</html>` like below example. the reason is jquery or javascripts must see the elements that you are targeting, so the hierarchy is elements first before javascript functionality.

```
</body>

    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

simply you used submit button

```
<button class="btn btn-success" id="singlebutton" type="submit"><b>Add User</b></button>
```

which will submit your form or at least will refresh the page

change it to button and it will be okay

```
<button class="btn btn-success" id="singlebutton" type="button"><b>Add User</b></button>
```

Comment: @KaoriYui has solved the issue with his comment. Thank you.